# How can I check if PHP Composer autoload is working?

Tags: php, composer-php

I am trying to transfer a small web application, which uses PHP Composer, from an old out of date server to a new server.

On the new server, I have run `composer install` to install the dependencies from the `composer.lock` file.

The web application requires a config file to set itself up (not that it does a lot of setting up), which includes the line

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

…which *should* locate the autoloader relative to the config file, and make the packages installed by Composer known to the system.

However, this doesn't seem to be working properly, as when the web app tries to use SwiftMailer (which was installed via Composer), it says:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance()

…in the file that calls it, which obviously suggests that it does not know about it and cannot find it.

Is there a way that I can meaningfully check what the result of the autoloader include is and see what it is (or is not) doing?

Comment: `newInstance()` is not a current method in that class. It seems that your code is expecting an older version of Swift than what your new server has installed. This could happen if you ran `composer update` on the new server or if the project's repository received commits that were never installed to the old server. I'd run `composer show` on both servers to see if the versions of Swift match. You might be able to just update the `composer.json` to lock it to an older version.

Comment: I'd also ensure that you're running the same PHP version on both servers, which could cause dependency version mismatching. The most surefire way of achieving what you're after right now would be using Docker or something, that way you can isolate all dependencies, versions, etc

Comment: @AlexHowansky, well spotted, thank you! I *was* reviewing the site code against the SwiftMailer v6 docs, but at the end of a long day with fairly slow progress overall, I think my eyes were now seeing what they wanted to see and I did not notice these (subtle) changes to the methods! I have updated the code (as I said, luckily it was a simple app!) and it now works, so my thinking that Composer may have been the cause of the problem was mistaken!

Comment: @dir, hauling these old in-house apps from an old PHP 5 server (and old OS) to a new PHP 7 server was a major reason for moving them. In an ideal world we would have the time and resources to investigate Docker, etc, but sadly, today is not that day for us! Thanks! ;-)

Comment: Thanks to @AlexHowansky, my question is now resolved (it turns out that my initial diagnosis of what may have been causing the problem was in fact incorrect). What is the appropriate "SO way" for me to now close this question? Should I just delete it?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure to add a use statement to your classes. You can arrange your classes and give your classes namespaces then allow composer to also auto-load your classes.
You can tell composer how your classes are arranged according to namespaces as follows:
In the autoload section of your composer.json file edit it to know how the namespaces of your classes is arranged

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/",
        "Mynamespace\\": "lib/src/ProjectSrc/"
    }
},
```

The autoload section now tells composer the Classes in the ProjectSrc folder will have a root namespace of Mynamespace. From this information composer can determine all other sub namespaces in your directory tree. This will not happen automatically composer has to rebuild its mapping of classes with the  `composer dump-autoload` command.

Comment: Please share more details. How does this resolve the given error message?

Comment: @Alex Howansky has answered the question.